# Password protected storage server which can be accessed programmatically (like Amazon S3)

Tags: amazon-s3

We want to store our files somewhere on a storage server, some of which need to be password protected. S3 is a very good option since

- it can be password protected.
- we can access it programmatically (say we can upload or download files from java)

Although the storage is cheap, download/upload price on S3 is not that cheap. So we are looking for alternatives. One option is to use our own servers. Is there any way to simulate a similar behavior with a personal server?

Comment: S3 is very cheap. How many accesses do you expect per month and how much data do you have?

Comment: We want save our models in S3 (models of machine learning systems); each of them are around 1G. But the thing is the models are used inside our codes and which need to download them (models on S3) each time we have a fresh version copy of the code, as well as CI system for automatic testing. Rough estimate is: 20 models, each needed to be downloaded at least 10000 times a month (so 20 * 10000 * 0.5~100TB of downloading).

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using this: https://www.minio.io/
It's an object storage server that is compatible with Amazon S3